# ASP.NET Site: How to stop script from running in URL

Tags: asp.net, xss

In a standard ASP.NET 4.5 site how do you stop script from running when it is included in the URL?

For example:

```
https://somesite.com/default.aspx?<script>alert('Hello')</script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The page won't run a script like that via query string, it will at the very least encode it. At the browser level you can disable scripting usually found in the browser security settings, disable scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Please see below URL

https://somesite.com/default.aspx/%22%3E%3Cimg%20src%3dq%20onerror%3dalert(9)%3E

It will run in browser.

Using this way we can run script.